# Lifting smooth homotopies in smooth fiber bundles

Tags: fibre-bundles

I wish I had a reference for the following fact. Every smooth bundle on $M\times I$ is isomorphic to the pullback (via projection $M\times I\to M$) of a smooth bundle on $M$.

Comment: Is what you are worried about the smoothness?  For topological bundles, this is Theorem 11.4 in Steenrod's "The Topology of Fiber Bundles".

Comment: Isn't the proof just "take a smooth connection on the $M \times I$ bundle and parallel translate along the $I$ fibers?"

Comment: @RyanBudney: Would that work for general smooth fiber bundles?  I only know how to do that if the structure group is a Lie group (but I haven't ever taught it, so I haven't carefully gone through the foundational stuff and might be missing something obvious).

Comment: @Ryan: That's one proof. A slightly different one involves flowing along a lifted vector field. It's also good to extend this conclusion to bundles where the base is an $n$-dimensional cube or disk or simplex, but perhaps this is best done by induction on $n$.

Comment: @Andy: I interpreted "connection" in Ryan's comment to mean "splitting off of the vertical tangent bundle from the whole tangent bundle".

Comment: And yes, I care specifically about the smoothness. Actually the proof seems to be easier in the smooth case than the continuous case. But I have the impression that,  whjile Steenrod's result is well-known, the smooth analogue is something that people either re-prove as needed or wave their hands about.

Comment: My impression is authors thought the smooth argument was essentially taught in every differential geometry course.  Maybe not specifically labelled via an individual citable "theorem" but the underlying core ideas were all laid-out.  Like so much mathematics from the 60's and 70's, it did not get a proper textbook-type write-up.  I wouldn't be surprised if this theorem is in Cerf's Ph.D thesis.  A lot of these types of theorems appear there.  But I have not read it in some time, so I have forgotten.

Comment: @AndyPutman: Tom explained my terminology.  I would call this an Ehresmann connection, where you split the  tangent bundle of the total space of the bundle over $M \times I$.   But I think there are many functionally-equivalent notions of connection that work.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: Ah, that makes sense!